# Java Runtime.exec escaped arguments in string

Tags: java, runtime, exec

Due to working through a framework, I only have control over the command string of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string)`, so no array.

Problem is, I need to pass some escaped arguments and it just doesn't seem to work.

Take this for example: `wget -qO- --post-data "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Devices><Device><FLOWCTRL>2</FLOWCTRL></Device></Devices>" -- http://192.168.3.33/data/changes.xml`. Works perfectly fine in the shell, but something is messed up since I don't get the proper response (most probably because the data isn't valid).

Edit: https://github.com/openhab/openhab-addons/blob/2.5.x/bundles/org.openhab.binding.exec/src/main/java/org/openhab/binding/exec/internal/handler/ExecHandler.java#L174 Link to code

Comment: could share the code that runs the command ? to see how you pass the string

Comment: So, this would be a little messy to continue down the path you've started, a possibly better solution would be to use `ProcessBuilder` which may reduce the need to quote any of the parameters at all

Comment: @MadProgrammer As I said, I have no control over this... I need to do it in one string :(

Comment: The shell may support quoting. You could use something like `bash -c 'wget ... "..." ...'`.

Comment: And why can't you use ProcessBuilder? You call getRuntime by yourself. What frameworks prevents that?

Comment: @dan1st If I try that, I get `-qO-: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`'`. And I can't call functions directly, I only have control over the one parameter

Comment: Did you use the java escapes too?

Comment: @dan1st can you clarify please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205172/discussion-between-consti-p-and-dan1st).

Comment: @Java escapes won't help.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I said, I have no control over this... I need to do it in one string :(

There is no direct solution given that constraint.  Period.

It is a plain fact that `exec(String)` does not understand any form of escaping or quoting.  It splits the string into a command name and multiple arguments using whitespace characters as the argument separator.  The behavior is hard-wired ... and documented.

---

The possible solutions are:

- Do the splitting yourself, and use `exec(String[])`.
- Get a shell to do the splitting; e.g.

  ```
  String cmd = "wget -qO- --post-data \"<?xml version=\\"1.0\\" ...."
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd);
  ```

  Note that we are using `exec(String[])` here too.
- Generate and run a shell script on the fly:

  1. Write the following script to a temporary file (say "/tmp/abc.sh")

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     wget -qO- --post-data \
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Devices><Device><FLOWCTRL>2</FLOWCTRL></Device></Devices>" \
       -- http://192.168.3.33/data/changes.xml
     ```
  2. Make the script executable
  3. Run it:

     ```
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/tmp/abc.sh");
     ```

Comment: Sadly I have to send different data. I also don't have control over the exec parameters, so no chance of the first two options. Seems I can only try to write a script that generates the data without having to use spaces... Thanks!